# Type Cast object inside a list

Tags: java, arraylist, casting, type-conversion

I have a list and am trying to add some members of Custom Class type.

```
List<MyCustomClass> myList = new ArrayList<MyCustomClass>();
myList.addAll(queryResponse.getRecords());
```

Actually `queryResponse` is again a custom class which has 2 members;

```
private Long totalRecords;
private List<T> records;
```

My question is I want to cast the individual members of `myList` (i.e. `queryResponse.getRecords()`) to `MyCustomClass`.

They are of type "Object" at runtime once the query is executed.

How do I do that ?

Comment: Are you really sure that it is casting, rather than conversion, you are after? Are the Objects you get out of the query _really_ of type MyCustomClass?

Comment: If myList is a `List<MyCustomClass>` objects, than you have to put only instances of `MyCustomClass` into it. Simple as that. Anything else throws away type safety. The `addAll()` can accept only a `Colletion<MyCustomClass>` argument.

Comment: @Natix: That's not accurate. addAll in this case accepts Collections of anything extending MyCustomClass (See List.addAll signature)

Comment: @EyalSchneider Yeah, that's correct, I just didn't want to overcomplicate things...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `queryResponse.getRecords()` return `Object`, you can type caste it like this

```
myList.addAll((MyCustomClass)queryResponse.getRecords());
```

Comment: If I do that, I get no suitable method found for addAll(MyCustomClass)...in my editor itself

Answer (score 0):

```
myList.addAll((List)queryResponse.getRecords());
```

should work, producing a type safety warning.
By doing this you bypass the compile time type safety guarantee, so it's up to you to make sure you don't get ClassCastException somewhere later.

Comment: But I want the individual members of the list to MyCustomClass

Comment: It would, but it is quite dangerous, because if the elements _aren't_ MyCustomClass, you won't notice until you try to pull them out of the collection.

Comment: @testndtv: There's no sense in casting individual items. They are all stored as references to Object at runtime. But as Bex says, you have to be very careful in the way you retrieve them. If you try to do it using a list of type List<MyCustomClass>, you'll get ClassCastException, unless the generic type of the added items extends MyCustomClass.

Comment: You should nor be using raw types except when you need to interface with legacy code; it's the sole reason why they are allowed.

Comment: My last comment is not entirely true.  You also need raw types to denote a class literal, e.g. `List.class`

Comment: @ViktorSeifert: I agree it's not the best thing to do, but I was still trying to provide an answer for the technical problem that was presented, regardless of whether it's a good practice or not.

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
List<MyCustomClass> myList = new ArrayList<MyCustomClass>();
for (Object element : queryResponse.getRecords()) {
    if (element instanceof MyCustomClass) {
        // this will never fail because of the check above
        myList.add((MyCustomClass)element);
    }
    else {
        // do something here in case element has the wrong type
        System.err.println("Found incompatible record!");
    }
}
```

This uses the `instanceof` operator to ensure the cast won't fail.  What you do exactly when the type of the object is incompatible depends on your requirements.

Comment: That doesn't answer the question. Note that addAll doesn't compile in his original code, which means that the generic type of the added items *does not* extend from MyCustomClass. If it did, it would compile due to the way addAll is defined (it accepts Collection<? extends T>). In other words, the OP is interested in a non-homogenous list (which is a strange design decision, but that's another issue)

Comment: @EyalSchneider I'm unsure about this.  It is possible that I misunderstood the question; I answered in the way that I understand the question.  Maybe some clarification from the OP would help.